# mcrypt_create_iv returns undefined variable

Tags: php, mcrypt, php-openssl

My encryption/iv code doesn't work. Whenever I test the login I get this error

> **Warning**:  openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended in **/Users/luke/Sites/user.php** on line **174**

I have tracked it down to **this** line

```
$size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$method = "aes-128-cbc";
$passWord = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$verificationNumber = openssl_encrypt($passWord, $method, $iv);
```

Mcrypt is installed fine as shown by this.
[image: phpinfo mcrypt settings]
Can you help or do i possibly need to provide more code?

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Ok thank you hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the iv size for "CAST": `MCRYPT_CAST_256` but you are encryption with "aes-128-cbc". That is an algorithm mis-match.

The CAST block size is 64-bits, the AES block size if 128-bits. Instead use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`, AES is a subset of Rijndael with a block of 128-bits.